# Resizing Azure VM image automagically

Tags: azure, hosting, cloud, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible to trigger a resize of an Azure VM automatically based on a set condition?

For example, increase from a 'Medium' machine to 'Large' if the processor/RAM is over 90% usage out for 5 minutes?  Then, obviously scale back down when usage reduces?

Or... is it possible to schedule a resize between (peak) UK office hours then downscale off-peak?

Just a thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worth checking out the [Auto Scaling Building Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) from the patterns and practices team, part of the Enterprise Library 5.0 for Windows Azure

> The Microsoft Enterprise Library Autoscaling Application Block
>   (WASABi) lets you add automatic scaling behavior to your Windows Azure
>   applications. You can choose to host the block in Windows Azure or in
>   an on-premises application. The Autoscaling Application Block can be
>   used without modification; it provides all of the functionality needed
>   to define and monitor autoscaling behavior in a Windows Azure
>   application.
>
> The Enterprise Library Autoscaling Application Block includes the
>   following features:
>
> - It allows you to use the graphical Enterprise Library configuration    tool to manage configuration settings.
> - It allows you to configure the storage locations and logging    mechanisms used by the block.
> - It allows you to extend the block by adding custom autoscaling rules    and actions.

Comment: Superb.  The XML example MS provides here appears to address both my points above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. But you can fairly easy program that auto scale. Take e a look at the [Azure Scale Me project](https://github.com/ActiveWebSolutions/AzureScaleMe). This uses calls to Cloud Services, but you can fairly easy add calls to the Virtual Machines REST API Calls instead of Hosted Services REST API calls.

Comment: I'd also add that scaling in 5 minute intervals can be problematic as the billing system for Windows Azure compute will round up to 1hr. So if you scale up for 5 minutes, then back down. Then back up/down again in the same hour, you're paying for ALOT of extra hours.

Comment: Good point, Brent! But I would not scale every / any 5 minutes. I'd rather suggest taking at least half an hour intervals. The scale itself may take up to 5-10 minutes. the point noted has been to scale up if given threshold has been exceeded for 5 minutes in a row. But then I suggest a "wait" period of at least 30 minutes before taking corrective actions for another scale.

Comment: Great point - thanks for that.  I had forgotten MS charge per hour so that's great advice!  I think lowering the power at off-peak times is a far more sensible suggestion (if we do actually adopt this).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a hands-free approach and do not mind using a third-party service checkout [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com)
There is a lot of coding, maintaining, monitoring and worrying about the nuance of auto-scaling if you end up implementing whatever auto-scaling solution by yourself with or without open-source blocks - and the cost that is perceived to be saved is still incurred when the auto-scaling solutions need to be hosted somewhere, sometimes at a greater scale.